# Setting focus on generated text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the below script which adds an additional field to a form on my page. I need to set the focus to the new field when it is generated, but I'm not sure what to do.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:;" id="addRow" value="Add Field" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
```

Javascript:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function(){
$j(function(){
    var rows = 1;
    $j('#addRow').click(function(){
        $j('#nameRows').append('<div class="nameRow"><input type="text" name="names['+rows+'][name]" value="" /><a href="javascript:;" class="removeRow">Remove</a>');
        rows++;
    });
    $j(document).on('click', '.removeRow', function(){
        $j(this).closest('.nameRow').remove();
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Being brand new to Javascript it's difficult for me to comprehend. I ask for help here because I get responses that I can then use to understand what to do. I did read through the docs beforehand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$j('#addRow').click(function(){
    $j('#nameRows').append('<div class="nameRow"><input type="text" name="names['+rows+'][name]" value="" /><a href="javascript:;" class="removeRow">Remove</a>');
    $j("#nameRows input:last").focus();
    rows++;
});
```

Comment: I was thinking it was much more difficult than this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using `append()` that means the appended element will be the last. So you can use:

```
$j('#nameRows :input:text:enabled:visible:last').focus();
```

The complete click event binding would look like:

```
$j('#addRow').click(function(){
    $j('#nameRows').append('<div class="nameRow"><input type="text" name="names['+rows+'][name]" value="" /><a href="javascript:;" class="removeRow">Remove</a>');
    $j('#nameRows :input:text:enabled:visible:last').focus();
    rows++;
});
```

Notice I added additional selectors to exclude hidden, disabled, and non-text input elements. Also `:input` is better than `input` as a selector IMHO.
HTH

Answer (score 1):

You can append the element and set the focus to the newly added element all in one shot:

```
$j('#addRow').click(function(){
    $j('#nameRows').append('<div class="nameRow"><input type="text" name="names['+rows+'][name]" value="" /><a href="javascript:;" class="removeRow">Remove</a>');
    $('#nameRows input:last').focus();
    rows++;
});
```

Comment: This solution will not work as it is not focusing after it is appending since the focus call is not inside the click event.

Comment: My bad, copied, pasted, added code to the paste. I've edited.

Answer (score 0):

Just reference the new element, and apply the focus method too it:

```
$j(document).ready(function()
{
//$j(function(){ no need for a second ready callback inside the first...
    var rows = 1;
    $j('#addRow').click(function()
    {
        $j('#nameRows').append('<div class="nameRow"><input type="text" name="names['+rows+'][name]" value="" /><a href="javascript:;" class="removeRow">Remove</a>');
        $k('#nameRows').find('input:last-child').focus();//<-----
        rows++;
    });
    $j(document).on('click', '.removeRow', function()
    {
        $j(this).closest('.nameRow').remove();
    });
});
```

That's all. You could also use `document.createElement`, and assign that to a variable somewhere, so you have a reference too the newly created element ready, too

Comment: children() won't work here because the input is not a direct descendant of the #namedRows element.  He'd have to use find().